# 500 internal server error on fresh Laravel installation

Tags: php, laravel-5.1

I have just installed Laravel on my host following the official site's step by step guide and created an app called core, using the command

```
laravel new core
```

after seeing the success message I uploaded everything to my host, but when i try to access the /core/public folder from the browser i get 500 error on Chrome and nothing at all on firefox.
if i run the command

```
php artisan list
```

On SSH inside my core folder i get:

```
Status: 500 Internal Server Error
Content-type: text/html
```

Can anyone of you Laravel experts let me know please where did i go wrong?
thanks in advance

In the error log i found:

```
PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in ...public_html/laravel/core/public/index.php on line 50
```

even though i haven't touched any files, line 50 is:

```
$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);
```

I checked all the requirement from Laravel and my server meets them all
PHP >= 5.5.9
OpenSSL PHP Extension
PDO PHP Extension
Mbstring PHP Extension
Tokenizer PHP Extension

The application key was successfully generated inside .env
Also Directories within the storage and the bootstrap/cache directories are writable by the web server with permission 755

Comment: 'Internal Server Error' should generate something in the system's `php` and/or `apache` log. Have a look in those and report your findings.

Comment: Is your web server pointing the document root to `core/` or to `core/public/`? Because it should be pointing to the second one.

Comment: This question is off-topic for Stack Overflow as it is not about programming.

Comment: The error log shows
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'class' (T_CLASS), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$' in ...public_html/laravel/core/public/index.php on line 50

Comment: Did you set the app key?

Comment: What version of PHP are you running?

Comment: You might want to take this to chat: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11/php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unexpected class for `Kernel::class` implies to me that you are running a version of PHP lower than 5.5. [Laravel only works for  5.5.9+](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/installation).

My guess is your server provider claims to have PHP 5.5+ support, but the boxes may come with 5.4 installed on them. You will need to contact your server admin to get them to upgrade it if you cannot upgrade it yourself.

PHP 5.5 is required because the `::class` syntax was added in that version.

Comment: For some reason phpinfo was showing 5.5.9 which is not the right version running on the server, so you were right, i had to go and configure the server to use 5.6 and it worked. Thanks